# NSAttributedString won't show correct font

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I have a label showing HTML through this `NSAttributedString` function.
The problem is that I want to add a custom font to it, but it does not add the font.

What have I done wrong?

Here is my code:

```
extension String {
    func convertHtml() -> NSAttributedString {
        let titleAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.headline), NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]

        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
        do{
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data,
                                          options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                                                    .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
                                          documentAttributes: nil)

        }catch{
            return NSAttributedString.init(string: self, attributes: titleAttributes)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You make no use of `titleAttributes` if the attributed string is created as HTML from the string.

Comment: @rmaddy Aaaah that's right. But how do I add it to the NSAttributedString inside the `do`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to replace all font settings from the resulting HTML, you need to apply your `titleAttributes` after creating the attributed string from the HTML string.

```
extension String {
    func convertHtml() -> NSAttributedString {
        let titleAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: UIFontTextStyle.headline), NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.black]

        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
        do{
            let res = try NSAttributedString(data: data,
                                          options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                                                    .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],
                                          documentAttributes: nil)
            let mutable = res.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableAttributedString
            mutable.addAttributes(titleAttributes, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: res.length))

            return mutable
        }catch{
            return NSAttributedString.init(string: self, attributes: titleAttributes)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Get an error here: `let mutable = [res mutableCopy]` saying it needs to separate res and mutableCopy and that it cannot find mutableCopy?

Comment: If I change it to `[res.mutableCopy()]` it says that [Any] cannot be a `NSMutableAttributedString`

Comment: Worked without the `[]`

Comment: Oops. Old Objective-C habit. Fixed answer.

Comment: I know it was already like this but `guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else {` is pointless. The else part will never be executed considering that Swift strings are utf8. You can simply force unwrap or you can use Data initializer and pass the string utf8 property. Btw why don't you use `NSMutableAttributedString` initializer ? `NSMutableAttributedString(data: Data(utf8), options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)`

Comment: I would also explicitly set the title attributes type: `let titleAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [.font: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline), .foregroundColor: UIColor.black]`